# Как удалить определённый элемент из массива при нажатии на кнопку удаления

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

В общем, есть у меня TODO лист. Там я в поле ввода вожу какое-то дело, оно появляется на экране с кнопками "Готово" и "Удалить".

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку «Удалить» удалялся не только DOM-элемент `li` из DOM-дерева, но и объект в массиве дел. При клике на кнопку «Удалить» необходимо найти в массиве дел объект с таким же id и удалить его.

При нажатии "Удалить" у меня удаляется элемент, но именно первый. Поиск осуществляю по `idOfItem` каждого дела, которому я присваиваю рандомное значение с помощью функции (за этот пункт не ругайте, тут всё как надо).

Я запутался короче. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Само удаление происходит в последней функции `createTodoApp` в `todoItem.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function ()`.

```
function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);    // я использовал рандомайзер, чтобы новым ДЕЛАМ применять рандомные id
}


let arrayOfNames = [];
class nameOfItem {                          // класс, для создания массива и элементов в него из ДЕЛ, которые добавляются в тудулист
    constructor(id, name, done) {
        this.name = name;
        this.done = done;
        this.idOfItem = getRandomFloat(1, 1000);
        arrayOfNames.push(['id:', this.idOfItem, 'name:', this.name, 'done:', this.done]);
        console.log(arrayOfNames);

    }
}

function createTodoItem(name) {

    let item = document.createElement('li');  // создаём элемент li, который будем помещать в список
    let buttonGroup = document.createElement('div');  // группа кнопок для их объединения
    let doneButton = document.createElement('button');  // кнопка для отметки дела, как "сделанное"
    let deleteButton = document.createElement('button'); // кнопка для удаления дела
    let done = false;
    let idOfItem = 1;


    const nameOfThisItem = new nameOfItem(idOfItem, name, done);

    item.classList.add('list-group-item', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
    item.textContent = nameOfThisItem.name;

    buttonGroup.classList.add('btn-group', 'btn-group-sm');
    doneButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-success');
    doneButton.textContent = "Готово";
    deleteButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger');
    deleteButton.textContent = 'Удалить';

    buttonGroup.append(doneButton);
    buttonGroup.append(deleteButton);
    item.append(buttonGroup);  // вкладываем группу кнопок в item (то есть в li)

    return {
        item, doneButton, deleteButton,
    }

}




function createTodoApp(container, title = 'Список дел') {

    let todoAppTitle = createAppTitle(title);
    let todoItemForm = createTodoItemForm();
    let todoList = createTodoList();

    container.append(todoAppTitle);
    container.append(todoItemForm.form);
    container.append(todoList);

    todoItemForm.form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!todoItemForm.input.value) {
            return
        }

        let todoItem = createTodoItem(todoItemForm.input.value);                  // применение ДЕЛУ состояние, как СДЕЛАННОЕ
        todoItem.doneButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            todoItem.item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success');
        });

        todoItem.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function () {           // удаление ДЕЛА (+ при удалении надо удалить соответствующий элемент из массива)
            if (confirm('Вы уверены?')) {
                todoItem.item.remove();
                arrayOfNames.splice(arrayOfNames.findIndex(i => i.idOfItem == arrayOfNames.idOfItem), 1);  // тут я пытаюсь понять как мне найти id того элемента из массива, который удаляю

                console.log(arrayOfNames);
            }
        });

        todoList.append(todoItem.item);

        todoItemForm.input.value = '';
    });
}

window.createTodoApp = createTodoApp;
```

Comment: Есть несколько способов: 1. Посчитать порядковый номер элемента li и удалить из массива, 2. Кнопке через data атрибут присвоить индекс элемента и при клике получить его и удалить соответственно из массива, 3. При создании элемента кнопки сразу определять обработчик клика и передавать в него индекс

Comment: После первого же удаления индексы в способах 2 и 3 поплывут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку «Удалить» удалялся не только DOM-элемент li из DOM-дерева, но и объект в массиве дел. При клике на кнопку «Удалить» необходимо найти в массиве дел объект с таким же id и удалить его.

Предложу такое решение для работы со списком.

```js
const arr = []
const oi = document.querySelector('input')
const ou = document.querySelector('ul')
ou.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const o = e.target
  if (o.tagName != 'BUTTON') return
  if (!o.classList.contains('del')) return
  const ol = o.closest('li')
  const id = ol.dataset.id
  const i = arr.findIndex(o => o.id === id)
  arr.splice(i, 1)
  console.log(arr)
  ol.remove()
})
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const o = {
    id: uuidv4(),
    value: oi.value
  }
  arr.push(o)
  const ol = document.createElement('li')
  ol.dataset.id = o.id
  ol.textContent = oi.value
  const ob = document.createElement('button')
  ob.textContent = 'Удалить'
  ob.classList.add('del')
  ol.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', ob)
  ou.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', ol)
  oi.value = ''
})
//
function uuidv4() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}
```

```html
<input />
<button>+</button>
<ul>
</ul>
```